# Solve redundant hostnames in Play Framework

Tags: .htaccess, playframework, playframework-2.0

In my Play 2.4.x Web Application I am getting told by Google Analytics that I have two redundant hostnames namely

```
domain.net
www.domain.net
```

From an SEO standpoint it's important for me to fix this isse.
Normally this could be fixed with a `.htaccess` file doing a redirect from one of those two to the other one.

I want to know how I can achive the same solution using Play's `application.conf` file. 
Reading the documentation I figured something like this could solve the issue:

```
%production%.application.baseUrl="http://domain.net/"
```

I am not sure though if this is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create a filter that checks the incoming hostname, and if it's www.domain.net, redirect to domain.net. This would be equivalent to the Apache .htaccess. Of course, if you have a reverse proxy in front of Play (which you probably should, this is considered good practice) eg nginx or haproxy, then you can implement the redirect in there.